# ansible: 'dict object' has no attribute 'port'

Tags: ansible

i'm trying to run the ansible-kafka playbook clone from the github repo and happen to be receiving below 'dict object' has no attribute 'port'

where am i going wrong with this

github repo : https://github.com/jaytaylor/ansible-kafka

playbook.yml

```
---

- hosts: dev

  roles:
   - ansible-kafka

  vars:
    zookeeper_hosts: "kafka-d1:2181,kafka-d2:2181,kafka-d3:2181"
    kafka_zookeeper_hosts: [ 'kafka-d1','kafka-d2','kafka-d3' ]
    kafka_zookeeper_port: 2181
    kafka_hosts:
      - dev
    kafka_healthcheck_address: "kafka-d1:2181,kafka-d2:2181,kafka-d3:2181/kafka"
    kafka_server_port: 9092
    kafka_connection_string: [ 'kafka-d1','kafka-d2','kafka-d3' ]

- name: "Generate the kafka hosts connection string"
  set_fact: kafka_connection_string="{{ kafka_hosts | join(':' ~ kafka_server.port ~ ',') }}:{{ kafka_server.port }}"
```

> TASK [ansible-kafka : Generate the kafka hosts connection string]
>   ******************************************************************************************** fatal: [kafka-d1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
>   with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no
>   attribute 'port'\n\nThe error appears to have been in
>   '/home/ahshan.md/ansible/ansible-kafka/tasks/kafka-cfg.yml': line 31,
>   column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears

Answer (score 0):

```
set_fact: kafka_connection_string="{{ kafka_hosts | join(':' ~ kafka_server_port ~ ',') }}:{{ kafka_server_port }}"
```

Underscore instead of a dot before port. Just the way you have declared your vars.